# How to know if Windows halted while updating

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, windows-update

I'm working on a Windows 10 computer and I'm updating it.
It has been showing the exact same thing on the screen for the last 10 minutes.

I'm used to detecting if it has locked or not by looking at the HDD LED, but this computer does not have it. How can I know if Windows has halted or not?

When there's an HDD LED, I usually see the rhythm it is flashing which indicates if the OS is still alive and using it or if the CPU entered in a halted state or even if the OS entered into an erroneous state. In this case, I don't have that, so I need expect help on how to deal with this.

btw: For the CPU, I usually check the fans and the heat dissipated. If the fans speed up and the wind temperature rises while the HDD LED doesn't stay always on nor always off, it also means it entered into an erroneous state.

How can I answer to: Did it halt or is it just taking some time?

Note this is not just for this case, I need a solution I can also use in future cases.

Comment: "Did it halt or is it just taking some time?" - If its been more then a day you can assume there is a problem.

Comment: And what is it that’s currently displayed? Does the Caps Lock key still work? What about Numlock?

Comment: @Ramhound I can expect that too but, unfortunately, I can't afford to wait more than 3-5 hours (depending on the day).

Comment: @DanielB Those are good questions but I have no idea. There's no LED for those too. There's only PC with 1 or 2 LED. 1 is the one that tells if the PC is ON/sleep/OFF, the other tells if <kbd>FN</kbd> is ON/OFF. Some don't even have both.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Windows takes forever to update itself and won't show an active HDD indicator. This is usually the case for any .NET updates you have to apply, including updates that include .NET packages; there's an additional compiling step that's done on the fly and the speed of this depends on your processor's speed.

I'd give it no more than an hour on one update before saying it's failed, kill the power, and try restarting the updates again or restarting the re-imaging process.

Comment: There's no HDD/SSD LED and I can do simple CPU tests by checking the fan speed and the heat dissipated from the computer. I still don't know how to deal with this LED removal.

Comment: The same thing applies, regardless if you can see HDD activity or not.

Comment: I still cannot answer my original main question. I can get information the but the CPU but how do I get information about the HDD/SSD?